# How to do dataframe apply when each column is an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a training dataset where one of the column in list of words. Example below

```
    target   id     values
0    eng     123    ['hi', 'hello','bye']
1    eng     124    ['my', 'name', 'is']
```

Now I have a `clean (text)` function and I want to apply that to the `values` column. I tried below

```
train = pd.read_json('./file.json')
train['values'] = train['values'].apply(clean)
```

And getting error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I get that I am applying .apply to an array of string which is not allowed but not sure how to fix it.

Please suggest

EDIT: Adding clean(text) function

```
def clean(text):
    import re
    from string import punctuation
    from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords

    def pad_str(s):
        return ' '+s+' '

    if pd.isnull(text):
        return ''


    # Empty question

    if type(text) != str or text=='':
        return ''

    # Clean the text
    text = re.sub("\'s", " ", text) 
    text = re.sub(" whats ", " what is ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    #many other regular expression operations



    # replace non-ascii word with special word    
    text = re.sub('[^\x00-\x7F]+', pad_str(SPECIAL_TOKENS['non-ascii']), text) 
    return text
```

Comment: Please share your `clean` function

Comment: @AlexandreNixon added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `clean` function. This function is processing a string, not a list of strings but you are passing a list of strings to it. You should do something like:

```
train['values'] = train['values'].apply(lambda x: [clean(s) for s in x])
```

Comment: Also possible (and possibly more efficient): `train['values'] = [list(map(clean, x)) for x in train['values']]`